# Version conflict in android support library

Tags: android

I have this in build.gradle file.
All the support library version is set to 25.3.1. Still the Android studio shows error :

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 26.1.0, 25.3.1, 23.4.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0 and
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that
>   are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is
>   compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
>   the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion).

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jeyom.boxthought"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.thebluealliance:spectrum:0.7.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: can u share error log of image of error log with question

Comment: what version of targetSdkVersion & compileSdkVersion are you using? Is it 25 also?

Comment: Updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Error is Due to the app.gradle in the Library `implementation 'com.thebluealliance:spectrum:0.7.1'`. This error can be caused by dependencies used by the developer and also clash between the dependencies in 3rd party libraries

They are using the following dependencies

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

Check the [app.gradle](https://github.com/the-blue-alliance/spectrum/blob/master/spectrum/build.gradle) of the corresponding library.

You can rectify this by using reducing your target version and compiled version to 23 and changing the support libraries to 23.2.0.

OR try using https://github.com/kizitonwose/colorpreference which can be a similar library and update project to 27.1.0.(Not sure)

Or Simply ignore this warning.

### Second Cause may Be

plays service ads 15.0.0 is compiled with 26.1.0 it may lead to show this warning. Try the same with 10.2.1

Comment: I think play-services-ads is the cause of issue. When I remove it, the warning disappears.

Comment: palys service add 15.0.0 is compled with 26.1.0 it may lead to show this error

Comment: @YesudassMoses Try ads 10.2.1. It may be compatible with 25.3.1

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42374426/7915814) explains it really well. It may be due to the fact that one of your libraries is internally using `com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1` and `com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0`,  so you need to specify them separately with the same version. As far as I know you also need to make sure that the compile version is higher (which it is, but just in case). I had the same issue becuase of a conflict with Glide library. Because you don't have many dependencies you can experiment and try to delete some (third party dependencies) and see if the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!! All by myself!
Here's it:

You have to change the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to `26` (or higher, if you want to) AND

Change the version 25 dependencies to version 26...Replace them with the given below:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.3.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.3.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.3.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.3.1'
```

EDIT: Sorry, didn't see it's 3 years and 3 months old...but had a similar problem, so jus wanted to share.

Comment: 26 is so outdated. You cannot upload a build to playstore with this configuration anymore. Go with 29 at least.

Comment: Ohh...i didn't know that...26 worked with Android Studio so...but I already changed it to 30...it's jus better. Thanks for the info!